# Can the MFA be part of Access Token in AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, jwt, amazon-cognito

We are using AWS Cognito for signing in (not the interface though, but using the SDK's `StartWithSrpAuthAsync`), and we are planning on implementing support for multi-factor authentication. We would like to see if the user has signed in using MFA as it won't be mandatory, and the preferred way would be through the token as we always have that.

Looking at the Pre token generation Lambda trigger [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html), it says the `amr` claim cannot be customized, which makes us wonder if this might be provided per default. Through our tests we haven't seen this though so we are wondering if perhaps we are doing something wrong and need to tick a box or fill out some option?